# RSA decryption with public key and secret messgae

Tags: rsa, encryption

I cannot figure out how to do this. Can anyone help me out?

"Someone has posted 252777246551092327 as his/her Public Key and the secret
message 218966718175329221 has been intercepted. Break this code by finding its
Private key(s). You may find this applet useful:
http://banach.millersville.edu/~bob/math478/ModularExponentiation.html"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We will not do your homework for you.  If you're having trouble, please ask a **specific** question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the documentation you need on the Wikipedia [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) page. Here's a hint: `p` is 502769219 and `q` is 502769933. `φ(n)` is 252777245545553176.

I'm assuming this is homework.

Comment: Yes this is homework, but I don't really know how to do this stuff so I thought I'd ask. I'll have more specific questions.